# JAX-RS modifying project /tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I've been reading a lot on StackOverflow but this is my first question! I've read the rules but bear with me if I miss something :). Don't hesitate to let me know if I'm missing something in my question.

I'm trying to learn jax-rs but it is a little bit confusing as I'm new to it. I'm trying [mykong's tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-hello-world-example/) and it works ok.

I've been working under Eclipse and here is the exact code from the tutorial that I have :

```
package com.mkyong.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloWorldService {

@GET
@Path("/{param}")
public Response getMsg(@PathParam("param") String msg) {

    String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;

    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

}

}
```

I've been trying just to modify the line with  :

`String output = "Jersey say : " + msg;`

to let'say :

`String output = "Another message : " + msg;`

When I restart Tomcat in Debug, it still gives me "Jersey say :..." message, even in Debug when I look in the output value, it gives me this value... 
Do I have to republish? or maybe delete the server and reconfigure one each time I modify the source code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: After changes in *.java file, use maven to build it and deploy to tomcat.

Comment: I'm using eclipse. Isn't it possible to just build it there(which is automatic) then refresh or republish or restart in Tomcat to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial may help you configure it : http://ducquoc.wordpress.com/2010/11/06/eclipse-wtp-tomcat-hot-deploy/